# Number format exception: null

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am using following datatype in my database .

but I got exception as Exception as:

> in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

How to resolve it

```
btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    Thread thread= new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        { 
            Connection con= conn.getconnection();
            get_data();
            String Query = " INSERT INTO employees (Id,
                                P_F_No,
                                Name,
                                Date,
                                Guard/LP/ALP,
                                Incomming_Train,
                                Sign_off,
                                Room_Bed_No,
                                Out_going_train_time,
                                Sign_on,
                                subisezed_meal)
                                VALUES
                                (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

            try
            {
                PreparedStatement pr = con.prepareStatement(Query);
                pr.setString(1,data[0]);
                pr.setInt(2,Integer.parseInt(data[1]));
                pr.setString(3,data[2]);
                pr.setDate(4,Date.valueOf(data[3]));
                pr.setString(5,data[4]);
                pr.setTime(6,Time.valueOf(data[5]));
                pr.setTime(7,Time.valueOf(data[6]));
                pr.setString(8,data[7]);
                pr.setTime(9,Time.valueOf(data[8]));
                pr.setTime(10,Time.valueOf(data[9]));
                pr.setString(11,data[10]);
                pr.executeUpdate();
            }
            catch (SQLException ex)
            {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }
    };

    thread.start();
});
```

Comment: The problem lies in the contents of `data` - you need to print that out to see which field above would not parse as the specified type.

Comment: Please post your table structure as well. Are you sure that id is a string?

Comment: (Id=text
,P_F_No=Number
,Name=text,
Date=date,
Guard/LP/ALP=text,
Incomming_Train=time,
Sign_off=time,
Room_Bed_No=text,
Out_going_train_time=dtae,
Sign_on=time,
subisezed_meal=text) this is the table Structure and it contain first field as Sr. which is autonumber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if your variable is null and use 'setNull' method from `PreparedStatement`. For example:

```
if (data[0] == null)
    pr.setNull(1, Types.INTEGER);
else
     pr.setInt(1,data[0]);
```

Something similar for other types(VARCHAR, etc.). Oracle is trying to convert the value you are passing to the type it is expecting. In your case, you have problems with numbers, but it could happen something similar with String if value is null. For that, you need to indicated that you want to insert a null value as I described above.

Comment: my data is not null i am entering value for that field but and datatype of that value is number in database

Comment: So you need to double check that is not null, printing it as @Nim suggested. Anyway, take in mind my code if can happen that value comes null.

Comment: what u said is write but now now their is problem occur with my datatype I am able to retrive date value i got following error Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at java.sql.Date.valueOf(Date.java:103)
        at third.addition_of_records$1$1.run(addition_of_records.java:104)

Comment: The `Date.valueOf()` error is because your date is not in [yyyy-mm-dd](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)) format

Comment: In my access backend i don't have yyyy-mm-dd format I am using mm-dd-yyyy format

Answer (score 1):

This line:

`pr.setInt(2,Integer.parseInt(data[1]));`

Calling parseInt on a null value will cause the NumberFormatException you're getting, data[1] will be null.

Comment: I know that i got exception on that line but I  am passing value for that field

Comment: I agree with @Derek. Based on the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) the value must be `null`. So perhaps try and print the value of `data[1]` and check it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

use PreparedStatement.setObject() to avoid such kind of exceptions. JDBC automatically converts Object value to its corresponding SQL type.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject(int, java.lang.Object)

Comment: if I used preparedsatement.getString(index,value);then it's ok ?

Comment: i used the setString but now I got error as syntax error in insert statement is their any need to put value in place of Question mark.